# Is it possible to Draw/paint on to image and also to erase it in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

In My Application i am using this canvas code to paint.

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Bitmap kangoo =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);

        canvas.drawColor(0xFF00FF00);
        //canvas.drawBitmap (kangoo, 200,  200, null); 
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

    }
```

But while i am going to save this mBitmap, it is not saving the bitmap that i have put on the mBitmap. I mean it is not saved with the kangoo bitmap.

So whats the wrong in this code ?
Thanks.

Comment: Very unclear on exactly what you are trying to achieve here - try to show us more of your code (for example where do you try ad save the bitmap) and explain what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @PolamReddyRajaReddy : What you have done new ?? You have just copy paste the example from the developer site from here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Comment: @PolamReddyRajaReddy : Please read the question carefuly then do comment or answer. I want to paint on the Image and do erase on that paint. which is not possible with this demo app.

Comment: you have to give comment or answer as per the question. not for your own way.

Comment: Please clarify if you want to erase what you are drawing or to save what you are drawaing. Both have different answers

Comment: @rDroid: I am painting on the canvas. While there may be an image as a Background or may be a Color as a Background. And If i select erase then as like painting on the canvas, the paint where i touch the finger should be erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save the image after editing it, you want to do something like this :

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap=view.getDrawingCache();
// this creates a bitmap with whatever the drawing state of the view currently is (with your edits that is)
//you can now save the image .
```

Comment: I think you are not getting me properly. I mean i want to draw paint on the any image and then want to save that edited  image. And also there should be functionality of the erase from the image but not the image.

Comment: In My code i have taken mBitmap to save image. Then why should i have to take another bitmap ??

Comment: mBitmap will not have the edits that you made to the image. If you get the drawing cache from the view, it will give you all of the drawing that has been done on the view. If it suits you, you can do mBitmap=view.getDrawingCache() as well.

Comment: ummmmm. . .  Ok Let me try this one. Thanks for the nice reply.

Comment: Ok. Just let me know, Where should i have to create the object of the view ?

Comment: I am not able to do it. Where should i have to set the object of that view ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont't have your whole code. You will have to figure this out yourself. Call the method wherever you are trying to save the image. Your view must be shown on screen for this (it must have called onDraw() method to get the drawing cache.

Comment: Thanks for the help. and i am using that FingerPaint example of the API demos of the developer site.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5259/discussion-between-idroid-explorer-and-rdroid)